# Retrieving the RGB values from a chalk object

Tags: chalk

I'm using the Node.js Chalk module to add some color to a terminal script I'm writing, and I'm currently defining the original colors in Hex value like so:

```js
const chalk = require('chalk');
const t = { 
    // Primary:  blue
    primary: chalk.hex('#2196f3'),
    // Secondary: grey
    secondary: chalk.hex('#888888'),
    // ... More styles
}
```

This works just fine for when I'm simply outputting those styles to the terminal using something like `console.log`. But I would like to be able to use the same color values for other components which require the RGB vales to be handed to them. However, I couldn't find any method in the Chalk library that would output the RGB values (or ANSI values).

Is there a way to have chalk output the actual RGB (or ANSI) color values in an array?

I tried looking through the [Chalk source code](https://github.com/chalk/chalk/blob/main/source/index.js), as well as looking through the properties/methods of the instances.

Comment: Why not store the raw values instead, then derive the Chalk color (and whatever else) _from that_?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I thought about this, but the above snippet is actually just kind of a simpler version of the code. The real code basically imports/parses a CSV file, which has them in Hex format. I mean if I have to do some hex to rgb step, then store them as RGB for that purpose, then I suppose I can. But it would be simpler if there was just a way to get the raw RGB values from Chalk.

Comment: So include that context _in the question_.

Comment: (Also note `chalk` uses [`ansi-styles`'](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ansi-styles) `hexToRgb` for this, but vendors the package and doesn't expose this function.)

Comment: @jonrsharpe I went ahead and just did what you suggested, kinda. Instead of just using the hex values directly, I wrote something that converts them to RGB, then stores them as a property of the color values. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like there's a good way to pull the RGB values from the chalk objects, so I instead converted the hex values to the RGB values and stored them as a property of the color config values, and used `chalk.rgb(r, g, b)` instead of the `chalk.hex(hexVal)`.